# Python and tKinter - Is there a way to add recent files opened by the program, like any windows program?

Tags: python, file, user-interface, tkinter

Like the title says; is there a way to add "recent files opened" by my tKinter .exe program, like any windows program? I've searched far and wide, but haven't found a solution yet. Not a very experienced programmer tho. I've managed to get the program to save a file and load the file back in, but haven't figured out how to make a list of recently opened files that the .exe remembers and displays under the "file-menu" :)

Edit:

I've managed to get the list of the recent files, but i currently have it saved to and loaded from a .txt file. Is there a way to not use an "external" file, and still have the data stored until the next time i open my .exe? :)

Edit 2:

I've settled with using the .txt file and the recent files list now shows corretly, opens the right document and is carried over to the next time i use the program :)

```
# Import recent file list from .txt file
with open(recent_files_file, "rb") as import_list:
    recent_files_list = pickle.load(import_list)

# Export recent file list from .txt file
def recent_files_export():
    with open(recent_files_file, "wb") as export_list:
        pickle.dump(recent_files_list, export_list)
```

Comment: just like you save and load a data file, save and load a list of files and create the sub menu items dynamic, update this file at each file open.

Comment: you don't call close on the files, use `with`, no need to close, ads this as an edit to the question not as a comment, why not pass the file list as an argument to the functions, store the filename in a variable, don't hard code it N times, you will make a typo sometime

Comment: where do you expect the list to be saved, the registry is NOT an option, no need for `global recent_files_list` if you only read the variable, you still don't call `close` on the files

Comment: Thanks for the help @rioV8 Appreciate it :)

Comment: now you removed the closing of the file, `file.close` does not close a file, you need to call the close method ``file.close()`, or much better use `with`

Comment: Thanks again. Changed to `with`. Still learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Only the most recently opened files in the vsocde editor can be selected.
Type "ctrl+P",then it will list the most recently opened documents

Comment: OP wants to have this feature in his *own tkinter application*.

Comment: @acw1668 I think there should be no way to achieve it at present. I will submit relevant requests on GitHub

Comment: Here is the link:https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18684

Comment: It is nothing related to vscode.  As I said OP just wants to have this feature in *his own created tkinter application*.